# How to determine the resultant velocity and height of flow from a vertical stream of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

For a vertical flow of water that comes into contact with a horizontal surface (eg, water from the tap hitting the base of the sink), given the volume flow rate of the stream, how can I calculate the resultant height and velocity of the resultant flow that occurs on the horizontal surface at a particular distance.

The only things I can think of doing are using Conservation of Mass/Momentum but that only gives us one equation ($2πrvh = Av$ where $Av$ is the volume flow rate from the stream and 2πrvh is the volume flow rate at a particular distance away from the stream). This would only yield a relationship between v and h but won’t tell us the specific values of v and h.

[image]

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: What do you know about the stream, do you know the volume flow rate in kg/s?  Do you know the initial area?

Comment: We know the volume flow rate and initial area of the stream

Answer (score 1):

For the height as described in your clarified question, $hv$ will be inversely proportional to $r$, as you said, since

$$F = 2\pi r h v\tag1$$

is constant

[image]

The problem is how does $v$ relate to $h$?

It will depend on the initial height $h_0$ at the initial radius $r_0$.  That is, for a pipe with a narrow opening at the bottom, for the same flow rate $v$ must be higher than for a wide opening.

If we presume equal pressure after leaving the opening, Bernoulli's principle would give

$$v^2+2gh = k\tag2$$

where $k$ is a constant found from the $r_0$, $h_0$ and $v_0$ (from (1), as $F$ is known).

Combining (1) and (2) $$2gh+(\frac{F}{2\pi rh})^2 = k$$

and there is a similar equation with $v$ and $r$

plotting this $h$ against $r$ on Desmos, with $r$ on the $x$ axis

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6fon75bnaq

The blue line is the height of the water using, as an example, $F/\pi = 3$, $g=10$ and $k=40$

[image]

Comment: Sorry I think I was quite unclear in my question.... I've added an image to hopefully make it a little clearer. What I meant was about the subsequent horizontal flow.

Comment: @ Lucas answer edited

Comment: @ Lucas, the $h$ graph seems reasonable, but there's probably a problem with the $v$ graph, maybe best to assume that since $gh$ is small $h$ is inversely proportional to $r$ and then $v$ is constant.  That's all at the moment, tricky problem, best of luck with it